# mysql query in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I have a tables:

**1. ms_fields**

```
+--+------+
|id|name  |
+--+------+
|1 |Color |
+--+------+
|2 |Gender|
+--+------+
```

**2. ms_fields_values**

```
+--+--------+------+--------+
|id|fieldsid|value |ordering|
+--+--------+------+--------+
|1 |1       |White |0       |
+--+--------+------+--------+
|2 |1       |Black |1       |
+--+--------+------+--------+
|3 |1       |Orange|2       |
+--+--------+------+--------+
|4 |1       |Green |3       |
+--+--------+------+--------+
|5 |1       |Blue  |4       |
+--+--------+------+--------+
|6 |2       |Male  |0       |
+--+--------+------+--------+
|7 |2       |Female|1       |
+--+--------+------+--------+
```

My PHP code:

```
function get_fields_and_values() {
   $sql_result = 'SELECT `id`,`name`,`ordering`
   FROM `ms_fields`
   WHERE 
   `id` IN (1,2)
   ORDER BY
   `ordering`
   ASC';

   $rows = $this->db1->query($sql_result)->resultset();

   $fields_list = array();
   if(count($rows)>0) {
      foreach ($rows as $row) {
         $row['values'] = self::load_values($row['id']);
         $fields_list[] = $row;
      } 
   }
}


 function load_values($fid) {
    $sql_result = 'SELECT 
    id, 
    fieldsid,
    value,
    ordering
    FROM 
    `ms_fields_values` 
    WHERE fieldsid = $fid';

    $rows = $this->db1->query($sql_result)->resultset();

    $values_list = array();

    if(count($rows)>0) {
     foreach ($rows as $row) {      
      $values_list[] = $row; 
     } 
    }
    return $values_list;
 }
```

As you can see my load_values function is in foreach statement. It's bad.
Is it possible to change the first sql query to get fields and values using 1 request?
Thanks.

Comment: Since the query in the `foreach` is potentially returning multiple rows because of the one-to-many relationship, the way you're doing it is the correct way. You can `JOIN` the tables together, but it won't give you the data in the same structure as what you have now, so whether or not you do that depends on how you want the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Simple `JOIN`

```
SELECT f.id, f.namr, fv.id, fv.value, fv.ordering 
FROM ms_fields f
LEFT JOIN ms_fields_values fv ON f.id = fv.fieldsid 
WHERE f.id IN (1, 2)
ORDER BY f.id, fv.ordering;
```